# jquery not working on Wordpress

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, zclip

I am trying to implement zclip on my Wordpress site to copy the result of some dynamically generated text. I have code that works fine as a standalone html page with embedded jquery, but it doesn't seem to port well to my Wordpress site. I have placed the code inline on my WP site, but nothing happens when I press the "Copy" button.  Here's the standalone page code that works.  Any ideas?

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.steamdev.com/zclip/js/jquery.zclip.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(function($) {
    alert("This code is working.");
        $("#copybutton").zclip({
            path: "http://www.ultrasoundoftheweek.com/scripts/zc/ZeroClipboard2.swf",
            copy: function() {
                return $('#result').html();
            },
            beforeCopy: function() {},
            afterCopy: function() {
                alert('Copy To Clipboard : \n' + $('#result').html());
            }
    });
});
</script>

<body>
<button id="copybutton" > Copy To ClipBoard </button>
<div id="result">Markosian KA, PaÄ­tian NA, Nalbandian RM. [Relation between the membrane and soluble forms of dopamine beta-monooxygenase]. Biokhimiia. 1990;55:(1)147-54. [<a href="http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/2344453" target="_blank">pubmed</a>]</div>
</body>
```

Comment: BTW, I do get the "This code is working" alert on WP, I have confirmed that the correct jquery version loads, and I receive no console errors.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone running into this problem, I figured it out.  The code *was* working fine, but the zclip movie was not positioned over my button.  I was able to fix this easily by wrapping my button in a div and setting the position to relative:

```
<div style="position:relative"><button id="copybutton" >Copy To ClipBoard </button></div>
```